# Can I access Kafka Connect Worker config from connector or task?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am developing a custom Kafka source connector. I would like to access the worker configuration, such as key converter or value converter or schema registry url or zookeeper url etc., but I didn't find a way to do that. Any idea? Is that possible?

To be more specific, in my implementation of connector and task, can I access worker's configuration? I checked, the only thing I can get is a ConnectorContext from connector implementation, and it has only one useful method to do reconfiguration, but it is not what I want.

Comment: In the configure method, what keys do you have access to? Can you show your code?

Comment: I think you can access it through worker config file, somewhere in your code? If it is in same resource folder or on classpath